# Getting started with Alloy and SQLIte

Tags: appcelerator-alloy

I am very new to Appcelerator, i've got my head around using Alloy to lay the content of my apps out, and have got to grips with using the Firefox extension to create an SQLite database. I'm stuck at putting the two together though. I've tried the Ti.UI.Database.Install but I'm not 100% which JS file to add that coding to, or where to copy the DB file to. I've followed a few threads and tutorials, tried putting the .db file into the resources folder, lib folder etc but keep coming up with errors. If someone could just talk me through the basic steps that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is about using a predefined sqlite database in your app, meaning you want to install a db with preloaded records in its tables.

app/assets is a good place for your_database.sql;

then in app/alloy.js

```
Ti.Database.install('/your_database.sql', 'your_database')
```

finally configure the adapter attribute in your alloy's models with:

```
type: "sql",
db_file: "your_database.sql",
db_name: "your_database",
collection_name: "your_table_name"
```

Anyway, if you **do not need to preload** a database, you only have to define your models (here, in example, app/models/foobars.js) and configure their adapter with

```
type: "sql",
collection_name: "foobars"
```

This way Alloy will take care to create and install the database (including a foobars table) for you.